# Sending / Receiving a struct in C++ via Winsock

Tags: c++, winsock

Struct I want to send:

```
struct Client
{
    SOCKET socket = 0;
    float m_fX = 0;
    float m_fY = 0;
    float m_fRot = 0;
    bool m_bIsAlive = false;
    Powerups m_ePowerup = Powerups::lazer;
};
```

Client Sending Struct to Server:

```
char* buffer = new char[sizeof(Client)];
memcpy(buffer, &dataToServer, sizeof(Client));
send(sock, (char*)dataToServer, sizeof(Client), NULL);
```

Server Receiving Struct from Client:

```
char* buffer = new char[sizeof(Client)];
recv((SOCKET)socketData, buffer, sizeof(Client), NULL);
memcpy(m_pClients[i], (void*)buffer, sizeof(Client));

std::cout << "\tSocket: " << (int)(SOCKET)socketData << "\t" << m_pClients[i]->m_bIsAlive << std::endl;
```

Why does this print out as though m_pClients[i]->m_bIsAlive = 205?

Comment: What did `send` and `recv` return?

Comment: Don't use structs as network protocols. Use network protocols as network protocols. Using structs exposes you to half a dozen or more dependencies that you can well do without. The fourth argument to `send()` and `recv()` is an integer, not a pointer, so you should use zero, not NULL. There is no point whatsoever in sending the `socket` member to the peer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char* buffer = new char[sizeof(Client)];
memcpy(buffer, &dataToServer, sizeof(Client));
send(sock, (char*)dataToServer, sizeof(Client), NULL);
```

Looks to me like you meant for the second parameter to send() to be `buffer`, here. Additionally, if `dataToServer` is a pointer to a `Client` structure, the second parameter to `memcpy()` should not be a pointer to this pointer.

Additionally, your code fails to check the return value from both send() and recv() also. Just because you asked to send `sizeof(Client)` bytes, you have absolutely no guarantee whatsoever that this request will succeed, or that many bytes will be written.

The same thing goes for `recv`() too. You must always check the return value from every system call, be prepared to handle errors and every possible return value, unless external circumstances (there are few cases like that) guarantee that the system call will never fail.

Comment: In blocking mode, `send()` blocks until it has sent all the data or an error occurs.

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm using multi threads and blocking mode. Thanks for your help though!